# define input and output as list elements in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

Hi I am new to snakemake and have some problems. I have defined two rules below.

myrule1 works and does what I want but I am playing around with the syntax and try to make it a bit more advanced but have some issues. These are found in myrule2.

Is it not possible to define input and output variables as list elements?

Thanks, I know it is a simple stupid questions, but I have some problems knowing what to search for.

```
FILES = "file.r1","file.r2"
EXT=".p1.gz",".p2.gz",".p3.gz"

print("files: "+str(FILES),"\n")

rule all:
    input:
        expand("OUT{ext}",file=FILES,ext=EXT)
   

rule myrule1:
    input:
        R1 = FILES[0],
        R2 = FILES[1]
    output:
        r1 = "OUT"+EXT[0],
        r2 = "OUT"+EXT[1],
        c = "OUT"+EXT[2]
    shell:
        "myprog -in1 {input.R1} -in2 {input.R2} -out OUT"

##below doesnt work
rule myrule2:
    input:
        R1,R2 = FILES
    output:
        r1,r2,c = ["OUT"+x for x in EXT]

    shell:
        "myprog -in1 {input.R1} -in2 {input.R2} -out OUT"
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is that doesn't work? Show error messages, expected vs observed results etc... Note that snakemake has a `--dry-run` option useful for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you want to do with your second rule `myrule2`. If you want to use original FILES then you need to specify the input file again. This is also for snakemake to deal with wildcards.

If you want to combine all the input files you can use expand as shown below:

```
FILES = "file.r1","file.r2"
EXT=".p1.txt",".p2.txt",".p3.txt"

print("files: "+str(FILES),"\n")

rule all:
    input:
        expand("OUT{ext}",file=FILES,ext=EXT),
        expand("OUT2{ext}",file=FILES,ext=EXT)

rule myrule1:
    input:
        R1 = FILES[0],
        R2 = FILES[1]
    output:
        expand("OUT{ext}", ext=EXT)
    shell:
        "echo {input} | tee {output}"

rule myrule2:
    input:
        expand(FILES, FILES=FILES)
    output:
        expand("OUT2"+x for x in EXT)

    shell:
        "echo {input} | tee {output}"
```